# Two separate IDs in a URL?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, cakephp

I'm designing a website where people can see fast food stores close to a school.

What I would like it to do;

On the front page I have a selection of schools to choose from, I then click on that school, and I go to another page based on the $id of that school. That page shows me another set of categories for types of food (Mexican, Chinese). I can then click a category, and I want the next page to display to me the specific food types that are close to the specific school I selected.

The table that'll probably be used for this is designed like this

```
id | school_id | category_id | food_id
```

As you can probably tell, each individual ID is associated with another table that has either the school name, category name, or the fast food place/hours open/phone number.

How do I achieve this? I assume I need to show how pass both the school_id and the category_id and then use SQL to search for the entries that have both IDs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could pass both in the url... for example: http://www.example.com?school_id=1&category_id=2

Then in the code

```
if(isset($_GET['school_id'])){ $school_id = $_GET['school_id']; }

if(isset($_GET['category_id'])){ $category_id = $_GET['category_id']; }
```

Keep in mind that values that are passed through the URL are very unsecure and must be escaped /validated before you use them to query the database.

Comment: Yes I am validating them. I also knew about the method you mentioned, but i'm looking more specifically for the cakePHP solution, sorry to not have been more clear about it. Is it possible to use the cakePHP HTML link helper to do this task?

Comment: Hmm, sorry.  I'm not too knowledgeable about cakePHP but I did find this: http://www.dereuromark.de/2013/05/04/passed-named-or-query-string-params/

Comment: I wouldn't use $_GET, but `$this->request->query('school_id')` etc.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming, you want your request to be routed to View Function of School Controller, you should make your Link using HTML Helper like below

```
$this->Html->link('Anchor Text', array('controller' => 'Schools', 'action' => 'view', 'school_id' => $school_id, 'category_id' => $category_id));
```

This would create a link like http://www.example.com/schools/view/school_id:3/category_id:4

You could access these values in View Function of School Controller using

```
$school_id = $this->request->params['named']['school_id'];
$category_id = $this->request->params['named']['category_id'];
```

If you don't like the URL Structure and want to change it to say http://www.example.com/search_school/3/4/ to make it seo friendly then add following line in routes.php

```
Router::connect(
  '/search_school/:school_id/:category_id', 
  array('controller' => 'schools', 'action' => 'view'));
```

The beauty of the Cakephp lies in the fact that you won't need to change anything else and you could always change the URL Structure in Router File.